# \mathds{0} and \mathbbm{0} not working

Tags: math-mode, fonts, typography

It seems \mathds and \mathbbm are only defined for number one to nine, are there some fonts in math mode that works for zero?

Comment: The `\mathds` font only has the digit 1, whereas `\mathbbm` only has 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are all the fonts, I could find on my system. Just play around with those.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{bbold} % all ten digits with \mathbb
%\usepackage{mathbbol} % all ten digits with \mathbb
%\usepackage{mbboard} % not working here, but should have your digits with \mathbb
%\usepackage{bbm} % just 1 and 2 with \mathbbm, \mathbbmss, and \mathbbmtt
%\usepackage[sans]{dsfont} % just 1 with \mathds with and without sans option

\begin{document}
$\mathbb{0123456789}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: But the the regular \mathbb letters look different then, right?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik sure, if you change the font set. Just try it out yourself.

Comment: Just compile  my example and use on of those lines one by one. You will see how the look of the mathbb letters changes. All mathbb letters of your document will have the form of your selected font.